# Jenkins form too large exception on windows stand alone installation

Tags: java, jenkins

I am getting an stack trace error while trying to add a new user in Jenkins:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Form too large 203433>200000
```

I have tried manipulating `maxFormContentsize` to 500000 in jenkins.xml file but I am still having issues adding new user.

I have installed Jenkins in a Windows machine.